# playing animation movie in iPhone application

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am currently working on a game, which has a long story at its initial. 
It just telling the user that what happened before the war that is the causes of war.
So, I wish to show all these things like a movie.

I used the MPMoviePlayerController for this, now I am facing the problem while hiding the controls.  I don't want to show the controls to the user. It must be full screen video having no other controls on the screen. Also user have option to skip this by tapping the screen.

please suggest me if there is any way to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Set your `MPMoviePlayerController`'s `movieControlMode` property to `MPMovieControlModeHidden` to disable the onscreen controls. I'm not sure how to make the movie skippable, though.

Answer (score 0):

theMovie.movieControlMode = MPMovieControlModeHidden;

will diable all controls